# Moving Focus Inside a FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, focus, accessibility

Currently, we have a DrawerLayout containing a FrameLayout and a LinearLayout with footer information. The FrameLayout contains content fragments. In accessibility mode, the footer gets focus before the frame. We want the contents of the frame to get the focus first. However, the LinearLayout containing the footer information always receives focus before the contents of the FrameLayout.

We have tried adding `<requestFocus />` to both the FrameLayout and to the contents of the FrameLayout with and without `:focusable` and `:focusableInTouchMode` set to true, `<setFocusForward>` to the FrameLayout, and calling `requestFocus()` in the content fragment. `requestFocus()` returns true, but it doesn't appear to keep the focus.

### layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NavigationControllerActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Is there some way we can make the contents of the FrameLayout take focus before the LinearLayout below it?

Answer (score -2):

set

```
android:importantForAccessibility = "true"
```

in Framelayout content

Comment: That doesn't fix it. According to the documentation, services can decide to ignore it. The footer still is being read before it gets to the frame.